# Failed to start release app ported to the VS 2019

Tags: visual-c++

I'm porting an application from VS 2005 to VS 2019. I successfully ported the debug version but faced with issues during release one.

**First**, when I launch my release app, I got an error "MSVCP80.dll not found". It's strange because debug version successful find the dll in the "C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_none_24c8a196583ff03b"

**Second**, if I copy MSVCP80.dll and MSVCR80.dll to the release/bin folder I got an error: "R6034 an application has made an attempt to load the c runtime library incorrectly" and "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)"

So, there the problem? Is any DLL missing in my system? Or it is a build issue? Why debug is Ok bur release is failed?

Comment: If you ported your application to VS 2019, why do you still have a dependency on the VC++ 2005 runtime? You may need to rebuild some of the other components your application is dependent on here.

Comment: Because some 3rd-party dlls is still require VS 2006 runtime

Comment: 0xC0000142 equates to STATUS_DLL_INIT_FAILED. So you may have a missing dependency here. Try profiling your application with http://dependencywalker.com. That utility super useful for figuring out both static and runtime dependency issues.